# Python RegEx help: Splitting string into numbers, characters and whitespace

Tags: python, regex, string, list, whitespace

I am trying to split my string into a list, separating by whitespace and characters but leaving numbers together.
For example, the string:

```
"1 2 +="
```

would end up as:

```
["1", " ", "2", " " ,"+", "="]
```

The code I currently have is

```
temp = re.findall('\d+|\S', input)
```

This seperates the string as intended but does also remove the whitespace, how do I stop this?

Comment: perhaps you need `\s`?

Comment: Are you writing a postfix parser?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `\s` or `\s+` to your current regular expression (use `\s+` if you want consecutive whitespace characters to be grouped together).  For example:

```
>>> s = "1 2 +="
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|\S|\s+', s)
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '+', '=']
```

If you don't want consecutive whitespace to be grouped together, then instead of `r'\d+|\S|\s'` it would probably make more sense to use `r'\d+|\D'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\D` to find anything that is not a digit:

```
\d+|\D
```

**Python:**

```
temp = re.findall(r'\d+|\D', input) 
//Output: ['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '+', '=']
```

---

It would also work if you just used `.` since it'll match the `\d+` first anyway. But its probably cleaner not to.

```
\d+|.
```